# Variável em php para javascript

Tags: php, javascript, json, variáveis, highcharts

Estou utilizando o HighChart para criar gráficos, porem não estou conseguir passar o valor de `data` através de uma variável php:

```
series: [{
      name: 'Tendência',
      data: <?php echo $encodeValorTendencia; ?>
   },{
      name: 'Obtenção',
      data: <?php echo $encodeValorObtencao; ?>
}],
```

Já estou "encodando" as variáveis:

```
$valorTendencia[] = $value->Valor;
$encodeValorTendencia = json_encode($valorTendencia);

$valorObtencao[] = $value->ValorObtencao;
$encodeValorObtencao = json_encode($valorObtencao);

$dataHora[] = $value->DataHoraPrevisao;
$encodeDataHora = json_encode($dataHora);
```

O valor da variável `$dataHora` funciona, através desse trecho:

```
xAxis: {
    categories: <?php echo $encodeDataHora; ?>
},
```

Desta forma o gráfico aparece com a data e hora porem os valores de series não.

Comment: Tenta dar um var_dump nas variaveis fora de `<script></script>` e veja se os valores estão OK.

Comment: mostrei(var_dump) a varável $encodeValorTendencia e imprimiu isso: string '["2000","2000","2000","700","800","700","2000","2000","2000","2000"]'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para resolver utilizei a constante `JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK`, da função `json_encode`, ficando desta maneira:

```
$valorTendencia[] = $value->Valor;
$encodeValorTendencia = json_encode($valorTendencia, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);

$valorObtencao[] = $value->ValorObtencao;
$encodeValorObtencao = json_encode($valorObtencao, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);
```

E passando para o JavaScript de forma direta:

```
series: [{
   name: 'Tendência',
   data: <?php echo $encodeValorObtencao; ?>
},
```

Os valores apesar de serem números, estavam como string ("valor"): `string '["2000","2000","2000","700","800","700","2000","2000","2000‌​","2000"]'`

Ao utilizar a constante `JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK`, os valores passaram a ser numéricos, pois a [api](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series%3Cspline%3E.data) exige que os valores passados em `data:` sejam numéricos.

```
:string '[2000,2000,2000,700,800,700,2000,2000,2000,2000]'
```

Comment: Boa +1, só seria legal explicar o funcionamento do JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK, porque você explicou como arrumou, mas não explicou o que ocasionou a falha, se editar e explicar com certeza irá ser util para outros usuários ;)

Comment: Perfeita explicação. Parabéns.